# draw the sampling distribution of treatment effects if the null hypothesis is true

Tags: r

I'm trying to draw the sampling distribution of treatment effects if the null hypothesis is true for a 2-arm trial where N=340 (1:1 allocation), assumed standard deviation for trial planning purposes is 2.8, and alpha set to 0.05. Planned analysis is linear regression estimating 4 coefficients: constant, assignment to treatment (1/0), and two baseline covariates (df=336).

I want the x-axis to show units as raw differences in means centered around 0 so students can get some intuition for what effect sizes (mean differences) will lead us to reject the null hypothesis. It would be great if there was a second x-axis below that converts raw effect sizes to critical values for the test.

I want to do this in R, ideally with ggplot2. I posted a question to Cross Validated a few days ago but it was closed as off topic since it was a programming challenge. Hoping this does not get closed here as a statistics challenge!

**Update**

I think the {infer} package will get me there. As explained in [ModernDive](https://moderndive.com/9-hypothesis-testing.html#theory-hypo):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If I understood you correctly, it is to simulate data under the null, perform the linear regression, obtain the coefficient for treatment, and plotting the distribution of this coefficient?

Comment: No, not quite. I think Figure 10.10 in ModernDive using the {infer} package gets close: https://moderndive.com/10-inference-for-regression.html#fig:null-distribution-slope

Comment: This shows a simulation based approach. Originally I was thinking more theory-based inference, but I wasn't sure about the right standard error. https://moderndive.com/10-inference-for-regression.html#conclusion-7